# Using List(Of Interface) rather than a Collection doesn't populate DataGridView properly

Tags: vb.net, generics, datagridview, interface

I have a screen which can display three sets of data, from three different classes. However, it should only display one at a time depending on the mode it is set to upon initialization.

Naturally, these three classes (I have only written one so far) implement an interface (`IExportSelectionStructure`) which defines their shared property: `Selected`. There are no other properties these classes share which can be put in the interface.

[image]

The screen has the following code:

```vb
Private _BaseStructure As IExportStructure
Private _DataSet As List(Of IExportSelectionStructure)

Public Sub New(exportMode As ExportRunMode)
    'BaseStructure setup goes here
    _DataSet = _BaseStructure.GetDataSet(_Session, _Settings)
    With ExportDataGridView       
        .AutoGenerateColumns = False
        .Columns.AddRange(_BaseStructure.GenerateExporterColumns.ToArray)
        .Datasource = _DataSet
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm running in Customer export mode.
At this point,`_DataSet` has a three `ExportCustomerSelectionStructure` classes inside, along with the expected data inside each class.

However, when it gets set as the datasource for the gridview, the gridview displays three records, **but the columns are empty**, except the "Selected" column - which is a `CheckBoxCell`.

[image: Data is empty]

In terms of debugging this, I tried switching `_DataSet` to a `Collection`, and also got `IExportStructure.GetDataSet` to return a `Collection` - lo and behold, the data appears on screen absolutely fine, but I don't want to use a `Collection`, I want to use a `List(Of IExportSelectionStructure)`. I can't go any more specific than the Interface, and I don't really want to go any more generic than that.

What am I doing wrong, and have I missed anything obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this was a strange one.

After struggling for two days with this I realised I had to cast the list of generics back to the specific class I am working with dependent on the mode of the screen, otherwise the DataGridView doesn't know what class of data you're working with! As such, the code around this for me is:

```vb
_DataSet = _BaseStructure.GetDataSet(_Session, _Settings)

Select Case _ExportRunMode
    Case ExportRunMode.Customers
        ExportDataGridView.Datasource = _DataSet.Cast(Of ExportCustomerSelectionStructure).ToList
    'Etc...
End Case
```